# Django / Automatically retrieve models names

Tags: django, models

I'd like to retrieve automatically, in a loop, the names of the models located in a specific Django app inside my project. Does someone know how to do that ?

Best Regards

Guillaume

Comment: What kind of loop ?  Can you show us the loop (leave out the part of getting the models) ...

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.db import get_models, get_app

app = get_app('myappname')
models = get_models(app)
```

Comment: In django 1.3 this is now: from django.db.models.loading import get_models, get_app